# Can you identify this part?

Tags: engine, vw, engine-theory, passat

I have just had the cam belt and water pump changed at my local VW dealership on my 2004 VW Passat B5 and on the technical report they were kind enough to point out everything else they wanted to charge me money for. So this question is regarding the most "urgent" and "expensive" one in this report.

I spoke to a mechanic and he said a lot of technical things that I didn't understand which I know makes this problem much harder to solve. Sorry!

### Here is what I know:

- There is a bearing that is wearing out near the front of the car
- It is near a big fan
- That bearing is important
- If that bearing jams it may mean that belts (I don't have a cam chain) dependent on that could come off causing severe damage to the engine
- Would cost £918 ($1500 maybe?) to get it fixed at the dealership
- 7-8 hours labour (supposedly)
- They would need to take the entire front end off the car to do the repair (hence the price)
- The bearing is near the alternator or power steering pump or both

I am looking for more information regarding this bearing and any parts surrounding it. Hopefully to determine whether the given quote is reasonable or even if it is something I could have a go at myself given adequate research.

What bearing is this? Do you have any more detailed information (and a proper name) for this bearing?

Comment: It sounds like the cam belt tensioner

Comment: If @HandyHowie is correct, and I think he is, I'm not sure why he would call it a bearing, but the part your describing does sound like a timing belt tensioner. What I can't understand, if they just changed the timing belt then they had easy access to the tensioner, why didn't he change it then? It's kind of standard to change the water pump and the tensioner while changing the timing belt since you're in there anyway, might as well and not pay to get in there again.

Comment: Very strange considering that its just been replaced, I don't think it was that - I'm sure they said it was a bearing.

Comment: It's the mechanics comment about if this bearing jams the timing belt could come off. Only bearings involved with that would be the cam shaft end bearings, the timing belt idler pulley (has a bearing inside it), or the crankshaft bearing. If it's the crankshaft bearing and that's wearing out, you don't want that jamming on you.

Comment: On the other hand, it could just be one of the serpentine belt pulleys (it has a bearing in it)

Comment: `cam shaft end bearings` `crankshaft bearing` I think we're getting closer to the answer with these terms

Comment: Either one of those would be really bad to have jam solid on you. I don't know your car at all, but from the way the mechanic is talking it sounds like your 2.0L engine is an interference engine, so when you lose the timing belt the pistons will collide with the valves and bend / break them. The collateral damage from the collision is not pretty either.

Comment: Yes hadn't heard it called and `interference engine` but I am sure that there would be significant damage to the engine should the timing belt break.

Comment: Max, in the past when a mechanic had "recommendations" like this for me, they were also able to print out a quick quote that listed them for later.  Next time this happens, try to get a printed quote so you can research it more.

Comment: Yes that would have been useful!

Comment: @MaxGoodridge  Where you been?   :-)

Comment: @MaxGoodridge  Did you ever find out the name of this bearing?

Comment: @DucatiKiller No I'm still not sure. I've noticed nothing wrong with the car that might relate to this problem in general use so I guess it's not getting too bad.